# Firebase data missing after accidental deletion and restoring (from restore link sent on email)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I deleted the firebase project by accident. After getting an email that the project is scheduled for deletion, I realized the mistake and clicked on recovery link.

But now, Realtime Database data is gone and I see "Create Database",
Interestingly files in Storage are there.

This looks like a bug, I cant query data from Android app either.
*(have filed a support request with firebase)*

Am I missing something?

Comment: Since you already reached out to Firebase support, I propose to close the question here. There is nothing anyone here can do about this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be sent to Firebase support. There is nothing anyone here can do about this problem.

Comment: @Frank Firebase support told me it is expected behaviour and asked to wait for 8 hrs. I couldn't find this mentioned anywhere in the documentation etc. So this question could be useful to people in the future. (Instead of them panicking)